# Understanding nested transaction SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, transactions

I have this code:

```
begin transaction outside
go

begin transaction inside
go
print 'inside done'
commit transaction inside

update Action set IdUser = 9999999999999

commit transaction outside
```

This code throws an exception on purpose at "update Action set IdUser = 999...", because of a foreign key problem.

I wish to rollback in case anything wrong occurs. That's why I have an outside transaction. In real world, I have a SQL file with a lot of scripts, and I want to make sure all the scripts maintain in a transaction, so I want to wrap it in an outside transaction.

That code above is not working. It's printing "inside done", and then throws an exception. This print could be a big insertion.

What's going on? How do I solve it?

Comment: You want to unroll print?

Comment: I used "print" as an example. It could be an INSERT. In real world, it's an INSERT / UPDATE / DELETE.

Comment: Print is not part of a transaction. Insert, update, etc. can be part of a transaction.

Comment: What would you consider a desired behavior in your example?

Comment: The problem is that in real world, it is printint "(1 row affected)", and then throws exception.

Comment: I just noticed that if I change that "print" to a real INSERT. It prints "(1 row affected)", then throws exception, but right now, the table that I inserted is locked. I can't use a SELECT on it o.O

Comment: **Word of warning:** SQL Server has the syntax in place to support nested transactions - but not the functionality! If you rollback an inner transaction, this rollback affects **ALL** transactions all the way to the top of your hierarchy. SQL Server does **NOT** really support nested transactions! See  [A SQL Server DBA myth a day: (26/30) nested transactions are real](http://www.sqlskills.com/blogs/paul/a-sql-server-dba-myth-a-day-2630-nested-transactions-are-real/) for more details

Answer (score 0):

Just try your query using the below template:

```
begin tran outside    
begin try    

begin tran inside  
print 'inside done' --Insert\Update\Delete  

Update Action set IdSuer = 999999999  
END TRY   

BEGIN catch  

rollback tran inside  
rollback tran outside  
GOTO FINISH  

END catch  
commit tran inside  
commit tran outside  

:FINISH  
print 'END'
```